# Can I close a PDF file, export a picture to the same file, and open it again with Mathematica commands?

Tags: export, files-and-directories, pdf-format

I am asking this because I am drawing a plot in Mathematica and export it to a PDF format. I need to check the quality of the plot and may need to modify it and export it again. Sometimes I forget to close the PDF file and I have to go back to close it and run the Mathematica notebook again. Suppose I need to export a plot `pic` to PDF with the command

`Export["C:\\Users\\abc\\figures\\pic.pdf", pic]`

Is there a way I can put a command to close the file `pic.pdf` first (if it is opened), and open `pic.pdf` with another command after I `Export` it?

Basically, I am asking if Mathematica is capable of closing and opening a file by its path in another app, say a PDF reader.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible, but it would seem like a bad idea: what if you had made changes to the file you force-closed? I'm sure in most cases it won't be an issue, but that one time you forget and force-close something important, it will hurt! :-)

Comment: Since it is just an exported PDF file and I am not editing it directly in the PDF editor, I guess it is OK to force it closed.

Comment: `Sometimes I forget to close the PDF file and I have to go back to close it` This is not clear. Do you have the PDE file open from outside Mathematica?  say using pdf reader? If so, how can you close it from Mathematica? It is not the same process? A process can close a file it opens, as it needs the file handler. Can you clarify how you opened the PDF file?

Comment: @Nasser You are correct. I exported a pic drawn in Mathematica in PDF format and open it with a PDF reader to check how it actually looks. Basically, I was asking if Mathematica is capable of closing and opening a file by its path in another app, say a PDF reader.

Comment: What about comparing pic to `ImportString @ ExportString[pic, "PDF"]` instead?

Comment: A process can't close a file it did not open by itself. You need access to the operating system. There are many topics on this you are read about. It is not trivial at all. You need number of tools to do this. And to do all this from inside Mathematica? Forget it :)

Comment: Why don't you use a PDF viewer that supports auto-refresh once the file has changed? Under Windows you could use "sumatra pdf".

Comment: @grbl Is it possible for MMA to write the file when it is opened in sumtra?

Comment: @nanjun Yes this should be possible. Adobe Acrobat is one of the very few PDF viewer which block the files from beeing written to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, it's difficult to close and open application, but 
if you are using Adobe Acrobat, you can use:

`RunProcess[{"taskkill", "/IM", "AcroRd32.exe"}]`

this will send a WM_CLOSE message to Acrobat, and close **all** Acrobat windows properly.

Opening the PDF it's easy:

`SystemOpen["C:\\Users\\abc\\figures\\pic.pdf"]`

This will open the PDF with your PDF viewer by default.